Analysis Metrics Usage of Cloud Storage Data Transfer
I have a bucket with size more than 120GB on multi-region. There is data transfer between multi-region and region, and I need monitoring the metric usage of data transfer in some period because need to compare with the GCP billing
Here is the billing in last 1 week

I only found these metrics on monitoring dashboard, I can't find the right metric.

Is there anyway to monitoring the usage of data transfer on metrics, so I can compare it with GCP billing to make sure the usage.

This blog written by Don Zippilli might come in handy. as mentioned here try capturing metrics for storage.googleapis.com/network/sent\_bytes\_count which will help you in finding the number of bytes transferred using which you can correlate Data with billing dashboard.

@KranthiveerDontineni Ah, I've read before but didn't notice for "delta" metrics. I'm only see on chart in sum of sent_bytes_count by date. How can I extract it on table row by date? I try to download to csv but didn't help./
